# PlaceHolder is not working properly in Mobile Devices

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

Am working in jQueryMobile and PhoneGap.

Here I have a problem. When I use PlaceHolder;

```
<input name="text-6" id="text-6" value="" placeholder="Put something here" type="text"/>
```

It was works fine in Browser but not in Mobile. My need was Here I need to show the placeholder until user type something in that text-box. Placeholder should be visible if he didn't type anything but focus on that Text-box. This is because users typically press the tab before reading the next field in which case the empty text is already gone and the user has harder time knowing what to type. like [Twitter Login Page](https://twitter.com/) .
But Its Hide when we Focus on that textBox.

So I implemented it manually..

**Html**

```
<input type="text" id="test" value="Im a placeholder!"/>
```

**JQuery**

```
var placeholder = $("#test").val();
$("#test").keydown(function() {
    if (this.value == placeholder) {
        this.value = '';
    }
}).blur(function() {
    if (this.value == '') {
        this.value = placeholder;
    }
});
```

[image]

But when I click on the textBox; Cursor is showing after the PlaceHolder value.
[image]

**But My need is the Cursor should be starts from the beginning of the TextBox. What can I do in this?**

Comment: Why don't you try the html5 placeholder attribut, most current mobile browsers support it already?

Comment: Yea... I already tried that.. But in Mobile when we focus ; it will be dis appear. but it will not happen in browser.

Comment: This is because users typically press the tab before reading the next field in which case the empty text is already gone and the user has harder time knowing what to type.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var placeholdervalue = $("#test").attr("value");
$("#test").focus(function(){
$(this).attr('value',"");
});
$("#test").on("blur",function(){
$(this).attr('value',placeholdervalue);
});
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TKUt8/1/)

Comment: But in this code;(when we use Mobile Device) when we focus in that textbox its value cleard. i need its cleard only at type something.. !

Comment: @ULLASMOHAN.V use place holder and remove all the script http://jsfiddle.net/TKUt8/2/

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment above, I would work with the html5 placeholder attribute and a fallback for browsers, which do not support this:

```
// test the support
function hasPlaceholderSupport() {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    return ('placeholder' in input);
}

// and as a fallback...
if(!hasPlaceholderSupport) {
$('input[type=text]').each(function() {
       var elm  = $(this),
        ph = $(this).attr('placehold');
    if(ph) {
        elm.focus(function() {
            if($(this).val() == ph) {
               $(this).val('');
            }
        }).blur(function() {
          if($(this).val() == '') {
               $(this).val(ph);
            }
        });
    }
})};
```

You can find a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/axelmichel/vmzrA/1/).

Comment: But in this code;(when we use Mobile Device) when we focus in that textbox its value cleard. i need its cleard only at type something.. !

Comment: In case your mobile browser supports placeholder attribute, this seems to be the default behavior in your browser (tested it on an iphone with chrome, it gets empty when you enter something). In case you are in the fallback, i used the focus method - so change this to keydown.

Comment: @ULLASMOHAN.V be aware, that when you click in the field, it is not a keydown event. So the browser behaves correctly when putting the cursor behind your placehoder text.

Comment: Can I use keypress instead of focus??

Comment: When I try Keydown ; its also not fine for my requirement :(

Answer (score 0):

placeholder is an attribute in HTMl5 for input box .. so it better u give it as

```
$("#idoftheelement").attr("placeholder","your text in placeholder");
```

and to remove it ..

```
$("#idoftheelement").removeAttr("placeholder");
```

try this let me know if it works.....

Comment: But in this code;(when we use Mobile Device) when we focus in that textbox its value cleard. i need its cleard only at type something.. !

Comment: this will replace the text in text-box if its empty. Now your requirement is "the place holder value should be there and once on typing something it should change".. is it right?

Comment: best solution is on focus change the value of text-box to "placeholder" and then on keyup event of text-box compare the value with "placeholder"  if its different do nothing and if there is nothing in text-box set the value to "placeholder" and set focus with whole text selected!! will this help?

Comment: leave the placeholder as it is 
and use this .. 
`code`$("#test").keyup(function() {
if ($("#test").val() == "") {
    $("#test").val('placeholder');
    $(this).focus(function () { $(this).select();});
}
});`code`                     ........................ this will place the "placeholder" text in the textbox and focuses and selects it .. on user typing something that clears and leaves with what user types..

Comment: Yeah... currently I did it manually... but my problem is the cursr is showing after the text"Placeholder"..

Comment: var placeholder = $("#test").val();
alert('0');
$("#test").keydown(function() {
    if (this.value == placeholder) {
        this.value = '';
  //alert('1');
  //test.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "return SetCursorToTextStart(this.id)
    }
}).blur(function() {
    if (this.value == '') {
        this.value = placeholder
    }
}).focus(function() {
   
    $(this).setCursorPosition(0);
    
});

I tried these all... But :(

Comment: I Tried this.. 
var placeholder = $("#test").val();
alert('0');
$("#test").keydown(function() {
    if (this.value == placeholder) {
        this.value = '';
  //alert('1');
  //test.Attributes.Add("onfocus", "return SetCursorToTextStart(this.id)
    }
}).blur(function() {
    if (this.value == '') {
        this.value = placeholder
    }
}).focus(function() {
   
    //.$(this).setCursorPosition(0);
 $(this).select(); 
    alert('1');
});

function hasPlaceholderSupport() {
 var input = document.createElement('input');
 return ('placeholder' in input);
}

Answer (score 0):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/cuKxm/

You will need this jQuery plugin: https://github.com/DrPheltRight/jquery-caret

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    var input = $('#test');
    var placeholder = $("#test").val();
    $("#test").keydown(function() {   
        if (this.value == placeholder) {
            this.value = '';
        }
    }).blur(function() {
        if (this.value == '') {
            this.value = placeholder;
        }
    }).focus(function() {
        if (this.value == placeholder) {
            input.caretToStart();
        }        
    });      
});
```

This line:

```
input.caretToStart();
```

will put caret cursor at the input beginning position, and like in my example you can do this only if input vale = placeholder text.

Answer (score -1):

in second time you need to get value of input - use .val() too